# Modified files in /vendor revert to the original state on reboot

Tags: android

I'm experiencing a peculiar behavior on Android 9.0, and I would appreciate help in understanding and resolving it. Here's a breakdown of the observed behavior:

Scenario:

- Remount /vendor partition with ADB remount
- Push some libraries to /vendor/lib64/
- Everything works fine, and the process I run is restarted with the replaced libraries

Issue:

- Reboot the device
- All the replaced files in /vendor return to their original state

Device Configuration:

- OEM unlocked
- Verity is disabled
- SELinux in permissive mode

Additional Information:

```
# mount
/dev/block/mmcblk0p30 on /vendor type ext4 (ro,seclabel,relatime,block_validity,delalloc,barrier,user_xattr)

# df -h
/dev/block/mmcblk0p30 775M 432M 343M 56% /vendor
```

Questions:

- What could be causing this behavior?
- How can I change the configuration to prevent the files in /vendor from reverting to their original state upon reboot?

Comment: It probably occurs due to a backup restore mechanism using NVdata. It does not seem to adhere to Google standards; instead, it appears to be vendor-specific. I would appreciate it if someone could explain how it works in detail. Thanks!